# Why does my "resolution" change between API lvl 18 and 19?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to build an app for Android.

I create two builds, one with target SDK version set to 18 and one with 19. My config looks like this:

```
// API 18
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="18" />

// API 19
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />

// Other settings which is the same for both 18 and 19
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
```

The result is this:

[image]

This is the first time I'm using Phoengap. Can anyone tell my why I'm getting this?

*It turns out that `height: 100vh;` in my css was the cause to my problem. I have no idea why this works fine in API 19 but not in API 18. Removing this style solved my problem*

Comment: I tried to produce this in a local project, but was unsuccessful.  That being said my test device is API 16, so I had used `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />`  Is there any chance this could be related the viewport html tag?  Is there any exceptions being tossed out from logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest just changes how devices behave at run time.

Devices basically use this to decide whether to run your app in a 'backward compatibility mode'.

*E.g.* Setting it to a target of API 10 (Gingerbread) will mean that devices will still use the 'visual styling' of Gingerbread for your app even if their API version is greater than 10. It is good practise to make the target version the latest version available, so the style used by your application is up to date for all versions.

What seems to be occurring here is an issue with changes in styling between API 18 and 19.

Comment: But it's not an native app. It's purly CSS and HTML5. And it's the same stylesheet and HTML files for both 18 and 19.

Comment: But when it is converted to an application, the `minSdkVersion` defined in your preference tag, is used as if it was written natively. Therefore it behaves the same

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit slow, but I'm new to Phoengap. Does that mean that if I have a phone running Android 4.3, the GUI will look like API 19? But on my phone running the latest update, I get GUI of API 18? If not, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `targetSdkVersion` in my previous comment. Basically if the `targetSdkVersion` is greater than or equal to the version of the device the app is on, the device will display it's default styling, whereas if the version is less than the device's version it will go into compatability mode and show the previous APIs styling. For that reason it is usually sensible to put `targetSdkVersion` as the max currently available SDK version

Comment: It turns out that `height: 100vh;` in my css was the cause to my problem. I have no idea why this works fine in API 19 but not in API 18. Since I learned something new from your answer, I'll mark it as accepted :)